# How to make framework with storyboard and UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, storyboard

I made an app with two View Controllers and storyboard to them. At all everything works perfectly but at all I must to create framework from this objects.

The structure looks like this:

**Framework:**

> FirstViewController.swift
>
> SecondViewController.swift
>
> Storyboard.storyboard

**AppExample:**

> AppDelegate.swift

I want to present in AppDelegate first View Controller. After presented it user will make some stuff and after push the button SecondViewController will be pushed on the screen. This second View Controller could be dismiss by the user.

**The problem is:**

- I move all swift files to the Framework folder with right target membership.
- After init the First ViewController I have blank screen
- I do not know how to connect storyboard with the views

This two UIView Controllers are only the tool that will be added to the few apps later. The point is that developer can put first View Controller wherever he want and after that he will have the answer from Second View Controller.

I will be glad for help.

Comment: your question title is not relevant to the explanation. framework is different things. you need to do some google how its iOS app working and how to connect each view's and use of storyboard

Comment: Ok, could you tell me what is wrong in my thinking? I want to prepare ready to use API. I have prepared everything like normal app. The point is that I want to create framework that later I will add to my apps and it will work like for example UIImagePickerController.

Comment: there is no need to use any thirdParty APi for create your own framework if you do google like : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+create+framwork+ios&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uBZxV8T4C5HT8gfRiaO4Ag this is the best blog for it https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios